# I call notifyDataSetChanged(); for update list. When i typed in TextView the list is not change

Tags: android

I have created an adapter and i used Google Places API to show address. I call `notifyDataSetChanged();` for update list. When i typed in `TextView` the list is not change.

```
Activity 

    public class SelectAddressActivity extends Activity implements SelectAddressAdapter.OnClickInAdapter {

ArrayList<AddressList> addressList;
SelectAddressAdapter adapter;
        EditText addresseEditText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_address);

    final ListView addressListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.addressListView); 

                addresseEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);

    //Adapter
    adapter = new SelectAddressAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addressList);     
    addressListView.setAdapter(adapter);



        addresseEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {


        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable input) {
            scheduler= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                    GoogleAPIRequestHandler handler = new GoogleAPIRequestHandler();

                    String date= handler.execute(input).get();
                    addressList = new ArrayList<AddressList>();
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(date);

                    JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");
                        for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        AddressList a = new AddressList();
                        String addressJson = predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).toString();
                        a.Deserialize(addressJson);
                        addressList.add(a);
        }                               

                            } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (ExecutionException e) { 
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();;

                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the updated address list in the adapter. it still has old data so when you call notifyDataSetChanged() method it does not have any effect.